# load more when scroll work two time at once when scroll in speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hi am using ajax scroll pagination i am checked  when i scroll page in speed its work two times and when its work two time it send same id two times and its effective on result how can i solve this issue?
here my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    function last_msg_funtion()
    {
       var IDall=$(".box-mainb:last").attr("id");
       var cbid=$(".box-mainp:last").attr("id");
        $('div#last_msg_loaderi').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');
         $.get('page.php', {'action':'get','last_msg_id':IDall,'id':cbid}, 
        function(dataz){
            if (dataz != "") {
            $(".box-mainb:last").after(dataz);          
            }
            $('div#last_msg_loaderi').empty();
        });
    };  
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
           last_msg_funtion();
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: people don't realize that `scroll` fires many times a second

Comment: @charlietfl what can i do ?  for my issue:' (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution will be to use a flag to check whether there is already another scroll operation in progress, like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var loading = false;

    function last_msg_funtion() {
        var IDall = $(".box-mainb:last").attr("id");
        var cbid = $(".box-mainp:last").attr("id");
        $('div#last_msg_loaderi').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');

        loading = true;
        $.get('page.php', {
            'action': 'get',
                'last_msg_id': IDall,
                'id': cbid
        }, function (dataz) {
            if (dataz != "") {
                $(".box-mainb:last").after(dataz);
            }
            $('div#last_msg_loaderi').empty();
        }).always(function () {
            loading = false;
        });
    };
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (loading) {
            return;
        }

        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            last_msg_funtion();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: you mr you..
 yes you.
  always do right for me this si second time you solve my problem i wish you succes in ur life in all ways